# creating multiple elements in div class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div class that looks something like this:

```
<div class="objects">
X
</div>
```

How do I write a loop in Javascript to add more "X" to this class? Once that's done how do I split them apart when applying functions to them? Say if I do `$('.objects').offset({left: 50, top:50})` that will change the offset of everything inside "objects", how can I apply offset to just one element?

in a nutshell I'm trying to create a n number of letters and spread them all over the screen.

Thanks!

Comment: so you want to use jquery as well?

Comment: is "X" the letter or does it represent an element that you want to put in `div.objects`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript loop is no secret:

```
<div id='crazyLetters' class='objects' ></div>

for (var i=0;i<1000000;i++)
    //notice that I IDed the div
    $('#crazyLetters').append('<div id="cl'+i+'" >X</div>');
```

Now you have 1,000,000 Xs in your page and you can access any of them individually by their own id starting with cl0 ...... cl1000000.

Have fun!

Comment: how do you use offset with an id?

Comment: $('#cl'+number).offset({left:howmuch,top:howmuch});

Answer (score 2):

Put them in a div themselves.

```
var objects = $('.objects');
for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
  var node = $('<div>')
                 .addClass('letter')
                 .text(i)
                 .offset({left:i, top:i});
  objects.append(node);
};
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hqzJ9/